# "az ad app permission list-grants" doesn't match what is listed for the app in the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I am trying to troubleshoot why certain automation tasks don't work with a Service Principal I've created, most especially any tasks involving Azure Active Directory. The Azure Portal seems to clearly show that the Service Principal has been granted the Microsoft.Graph `Directory.Read.All` API Permission.  The portal also shows that this Service Principal has the `User.Read` permission as well.

However, when I run `az ad app permission list-grants` for the Service Principal, it only lists `User.Read`. This makes me wonder whether the `Directory.Read.All` permission is actually present. And yes, the portal clearly shows that `Directory.Read.All`  permission has been granted.

How can I confirm that my Service Principal actually does have the `Directory.Read.All` API Permission?

```
 az ad app permission list-grants --id db7a66b4-06ad-4412-9bbc-73cb34f96ce2 --show-resource-name
[
  {
    "clientId": "01b359a2-f452-43c6-b290-e5ea1b359f38",
    "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
    "expiryTime": "2019-12-08T17:07:04.550141",
    "objectId": "olmzAVL0xkOykOXqGzWfOAvNygY8CKVIummKcmVpwq8",
    "odatatype": null,
    "principalId": null,
    "resourceDisplayName": "Microsoft Graph",
    "resourceId": "06cacd0b-083c-48a5-ba69-8a726569c2af",
    "scope": "User.Read",
    "startTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

And a crude recreation of what I see in the portal for this Service Principal under Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > (Service Principal Name) > API Permissions:

```
API/Permissions name   Type         Admin Consent Required
--------------------   -----------  ----------------------------------- 
Microsoft Graph (2)
   Directory.Read.All  Application  Yes <green check> Granted for MyOrg
   User.Read           Delegated        <green check> Granted for MyOrg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found, the reason is the Azure CLI command `az ad app permissions list-grants` just list the delegated permissions.

If you also want to get the application permissions granted to the service principal, 
 currently it is not supported by the `Azure CLI` and `Az` powershell module, you need to use [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) powershell module.

Try the script as below, it writes output the API name and corresponding permission.

**Note** the `ObjectId` in the first line is the ObjectId of your service principal, not the AD App(App registration), you can find it in the `Enterprise applications` in the portal(filter with `All applications`).

```
$apppermissions = Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignedTo -ObjectId <ObjectId of your service principal>
foreach($item in $apppermissions){
    $item.ResourceDisplayName
    (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $item.ResourceId).AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $item.Id}    
}
```

[image]

The permissions in the App registration in the portal:

[image]

Here is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244325/retrieve-application-permissions-of-a-service-principal-using-the-azuread-module), you can also take a look.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, Joy.

As an aside:  Is there a way to get both the "AzAd" and "AzureAd" modules installed on my laptop at the same time?

Comment: I found out that, while not recommended, you can have both the `Az` and `Azure` modules installed on your laptop as long as you don't try to use both within the same PowerShell session, so that solves my current problems.

Is there any plan to add the ability to list application permissions to the `Az` modules?  It appears that the concept of AppRoles has disappeared entirely from the `Az` modules.

Comment: @RichardDLawson I think no, the two modules are different, AzureAD module will do more in azure ad than Az.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out, and it was less than obvious.

`az ad app permissions list-grants` lists oauth2 permissions.  In other words, delegated permissions.

My Service Principal's `Directory.Read.All` permission is an *application* permission.  That means it's a permission my Service Principal has in its own right without needing another user's authentication token.

I'm still trying to figure out how to list the Application permissions using the new `az` commands and/or the new `Get-Az` PowerShell modules.  If I find out how I'll update this answer.

Comment: `az rest --method get --url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{YOUR_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID}/appRoleAssignments`

Answer (score 1):

I found out you can get that output with `az cli` but by using the `rest` command like this:

```
az rest --method get --url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{YOUR_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID}/appRoleAssignments
```